# How to perform operations on heterogenous elements of Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have an arraylist as follows:

```
 ArrayList al= new Arraylist();
    al.add("Hi");
    al.add(123);
    al.add("Rahul")
```

Now, I want to perform arithmetic operation on the element at 2nd position eg. 123+200, and concatenate elements at 1st and 3rd position i.e. "Hi Rahul". How do I do that??

Comment: Please show some efforts. What have you tried?

Comment: and i want an iphone6 .How do i do that??

Comment: Please outline your requirement. The requirement that you have presented is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast it to `Integer` as it stores all values as an `Object`

```
((Integer)al.get(1))+210
```

And for `String` as well

```
 String str=(String)al.get(0)+(String)al.get(2);
```

Be careful with this as invalid cast may lead to `ClassCastException`.

Other than that avoid use of raw types, in [`JLS §4.8`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) clearly stated that,

> The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of
>   genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged.
>   It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language
>   will disallow the use of raw types.